# Calling Python script from Django Admin UI (on field value change)

Tags: python, mysql, django, external

I am new to Django programming, and have limited knowledge of it's architecture.

I have a python script (converted into .exe) that I want to run when a certain field is changed in the database using Django Admin.

I have MySQL database table with a Boolean field. Data in this table is accessed (modified) using Djando Admin UI. Django Admin UI displays the boolean field as checkbox in the Change form. I want to trigger test.exe script when the check-box is selected (boolean value = 'True') and user clicks "Save". Additionally, I want to terminate/ kill the script when the user unselects the checkbox (boolean field value = False) and clicks "Save".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Django's signals system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/signals/) can help you.

It allows you to run operations before or after a model has been saved.

Example of pre-save action from Django's doc (1.7):

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import MyModel

@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    # Do what you want here
```

#### Note:

As long as your signal's code is executed, no response are given to client. So for asynchronous work I suggest you [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).